# Comparing scree plots or explained variance of two groups with different number of features after PCA

Tags: variance, pca, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

I want to define the dimensionality of a group as the number of PC features that can explain 80% of the variance in the group dataset. This intuition seems to work for a single group, however, if I want to compare the dimensionality of two groups using the same idea, how do I mitigate the problem of different numbers of features?

That is if group 1 has (n samples x m features) and group 2 has (n samples x k features), does it make sense to compare the slope of the scree plot/explained variance for these two groups as a measure of their dimensionality? Or should I treat it as an unbalanced dataset and oversample the features, eventhough they have the same number of samples?

Comment: Did I understand correctly - you have two groups, you have measured several features for each of the groups, but more features in one group than in the other? You can't compare two PCA solutions into which you entered a different sets of features. You need to have the same features, and preferably use a multigroup PCA in which you enter all your data (from both groups).

Comment: @Sointu I want to compare the dimensionalities of the two groups but I define the dimensionality using the PCA features. The dimensionalities would be comparable, since they are independent? but they are bound by the number of features I have in the group. So, I was wondering if bootstrapping or oversampling would be an option to overcome this confound.

Comment: OK sorry - this is perhaps a way to use PCA that I'm unfamiliar with. Best of luck!